# Do electricity meters contain inverters?

Tags: power-supply, power-engineering, power-grid

In Germany the low-voltage grid is 0.4kV whereas the plugs in flats have 230V. Who is responsible for this conversion? Smart meter?

Comment: You are comparing apples and oranges, that is line2line and line2neutral voltages.

Comment: *Smart meter?* of course not because the 380 V / 220 V system has been in use long before smart meters even existed.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There **is** no conversion going on because it isn't needed.

The 400 V is the voltage between **two phases** of the 3-phase 380V grid.

The 230 V is the voltage between **one phase** and neutral.

Read more at: [Three-phase electric power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-phase_electric_power)

Comment: Is it still called 380 V grid when it carries 400 V nowadays?

Comment: Yes. It might actually be 400, and the "230" might be 240.

Comment: Assuming the phase angles are correct the phase-phase voltage is always sqrt(3) times the phase-neutral voltage. Roughly speaking 220 goes with 380, 230 goes with 400 and 240 goes with 415.

Answer (score 5):

LV grids in Germany and Europe usually consists on a three-phase connection with a voltage of 400 V (L-L). [(Global exceptions)](https://www.worldstandards.eu/three-phase-electric-power/)

However for harmonization residential distribution of the Low voltage grid is distributed to 230 V (L-N) for private households and continues using  400 V to others that need this voltage or 3 phase power.

Metering is a separate issue.

### There are many different meter designs

- active power in 3-phase 4-wire network with service to 1 to 4

> One to four tariff. Ability to measure power only in any two phases or in any one phase (when these options must be neutral connected).

- active power in one or two three-phase or four-wire network

> One to four tariff. Ability to measure power in only one phase with the conditions attached neutral.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Meters measure.  They don't convert.

Conversion between AC voltages is done with *transformers*.